# Why is the size of the Conv1D reduced from filter and kernel size?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

I have a problem. I have a CNN model which is used for an NLP problem. I have a question about this, which I can't find an answer to.

Why is the filter or kernel size reduced ? Initially from 256,7 to 128, 5. It is because of overfitting, but why exactly half 256 to 128 and from 7 to 5?

```py
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(
        Embedding(vocab_size
                ,embed_size
                ,weights = [embedding_matrix] #Supplied embedding matrix created from glove
                ,input_length = maxlen
                ,trainable=False)
         )
model1.add(Conv1D(256, 7, activation="relu"))
model1.add(MaxPooling1D())
model1.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
model1.add(MaxPooling1D())
model1.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model1.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(number, activation='softmax'))
print(model1.summary())
```

Comment: Please check these posts: [Choosing filter size, strides etc. in a CNN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296027/choosing-filter-size-strides-etc-in-a-cnn), [1x1-convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194142/what-does-1x1-convolution-mean-in-a-neural-network)

Comment: Arbitrary choice from the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most [CNNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Natural_language_processing) applied to NLP combine convolutions of different sizes (e.g. the common spans of 3, 5 and 7 tokens) as a way of extracting [*n*-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) features over tokens [[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025521000165). Therefore, different *n*-gram lengths allow one to model shorter and longer spans (relations in text).

Reducing the number of filters has a three-fold effect:

1. it forces the network to learn representations at varying degrees of abstraction;
2. it minimises the memory footprint of the network; and as you've alluded to,
3. potentially minimises overfitting.

Knowing this, you can reason more about what the layers `Conv1D(256, 7, activation="relu")` and `Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu")` are attempting to achieve.

**Further reading:**

- See Section "Convolution neural networks" in [[2]](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hkg-website-assets/static/pages/files/DeepLearning.pdf) for a general overview of CNN models and what model components are trying to achieve.
- See Section 5.10.2 in [[3]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07108) for some examples of different CNN architectures capturing particular local relations of temporal and hierarchical structures when applied to the task of *Text Classification*.
- See Sections 4.3 and 4.4 in
  [[4]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03820) for an empirical assessment of the effects of filter (kernel) size and the number of feature maps have on CNNs.
- See Section III-C & IV in [[5]](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A3279993/view) for an intuition behind memory requirement considerations for CNNs.

**References:**

[[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025521000165) Zhou, Y., Liao, L., Gao, Y. and Huang, H., 2021. Extracting salient features from convolutional discriminative filters. Information Sciences, 558, pp.265-279.

[[2]](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hkg-website-assets/static/pages/files/DeepLearning.pdf) LeCun, Y., Bengio, Y. and Hinton, G., 2015. Deep learning. nature, 521(7553), pp.436-444.

[[3]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07108) Gu, J., Wang, Z., Kuen, J., Ma, L., Shahroudy, A., Shuai, B., Liu, T., Wang, X., Wang, G., Cai, J. and Chen, T., 2018. Recent advances in convolutional neural networks. Pattern recognition, 77, pp.354-377.

[[4]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03820) Zhang, Y. and Wallace, B., 2015. A sensitivity analysis of (and practitioners' guide to) convolutional neural networks for sentence classification. arXiv preprint arXiv:1510.03820.

[[5]](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A3279993/view) Minakova, S. and Stefanov, T., 2020, August. Buffer sizes reduction for memory-efficient CNN inference on mobile and embedded devices. In 2020 23rd Euromicro Conference on Digital System Design (DSD) (pp. 133-140). IEEE.

Comment: Thanks for your qualitative answer! Do you have another reference for me?

Comment: @Test Please see the updated answer, hopefully this provides enough reference/reading material to suffice your curiosity.